# Proper way for recieving bluetooth transfer in android (stop bit)

Tags: android, bluetooth, data-transfer

I'm trying to get some data from sensor via bluetooth. The sensor is sending me 8 bit packages. The problem is that data has different length (few times 8 bit) so I can not determine the end of data.

Now I'm appending string together and checking for carriage return, but the problem is that this is specific for my sensor (in the end of string i have carriage return ).

The sensor data for one measuring is like that:

```
547.8  5.688  22.40  .0000 .0000  .0000 \r\n
547.8  855.688  22.40  .0000 .0000  .0000 \r\n
```

I'm sending this sensor data every second to android device. Android device is getting  8 bit chunks, but I cannot detect the stop bit.

Is there a way to detect stop bit or something that I now that I got the whole data for one input?

I'm receiving bluetooth transfer like in android bluetooth chat example.

Thank you,
Toni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There always needs to be a way in data to find the end of each block, and one just keeps reading until that point is found.  Often that is a complete line (ends with newline) as here, or it could be a count value in the first one or two bytes (or characters).  One can't rely on the data coming in one read or similar.

Note that a "stop bit" is something used on physical serial cables and comes after *every* byte so if of no use to you here.